# How do I use rt binding behavior with t and t-params binding?

Tags: aurelia

I'm using the `aurelia-i18n` plugin and I want to use the `rt` binding behavior to display a localized, relative time description based on a date binding.

This works fine:

`<p>${myDateProperty & rt}</p>`

However I need to use a relative time inside a resource and can't get it working:

`<p t="content_ReceivedTime" t-params.bind="{ time: myDateProperty & rt }"></p>`

Where the resource `content_ReceivedTime` is `Received {{time}}` for English. I get a parser error on the expression for `t-params`.

The requirement is that the content updates whenever the locale changes, hence the use of the `rt` binding behavior, but I also need to be able to pass an object for `t-params` where the `time` property is a binding expression as well.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested but this should work:

```
<p ref="received" date-time="${ myDateProperty & rt}" t="content_ReceivedTime" t-params.bind="{ time: received.dateTime }"></p>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I can use this solution in a lot of different places to workaround some issues we have using t-params.

Comment: Great workaround. Would be great if one of you could create a pr on the docs so we get this info in the Aurelia hub

Comment: It will be a pleasure @zewa666. I'll do this when I have time